# Is it possible to use the value of a variable, as a new variable name?

Tags: powershell, variables

Long time listener, first time caller! :)  So I FEEL like this is possible, it's just that the solution eludes me.

I'm setting a variable (`$thisName = "a"`) and using that to create an object.

I'd LIKE to use `$thisName` as, not only a property, but also the name of the object.

IS this possible?

```
$thisName = "a"

$theseParams = @{ Name = $thisName; DebugMode = $true }

$thisName = New-Object [PSCustomObject] -Property @theseParams
```

I'm WANTING the variable name of the object to be `$a`, as well as the `$a.Name` to be "a".  But I'm just resetting (or outright breaking) `$thisName`.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. It's also a misguided approach. Don't do it.

Comment: I agree with @AnsgarWiechers, this isn't a good idea.  Sounds like a bit of an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - why do you want to do this?  What problem do you think it will solve?

Comment: I was just planning to loop through, to create objects.  Okay, so 2 "NO" votes clinches it.  Thanks for the responses!

Comment: It would be much more natural to have a separate hash table for it, as these allow property syntax for keys. Note that recent versions of PowerShell make it particularly easy to create custom objects this way by casting directly, so (e.g.) `$modes = @{}; $modes."$thisName" = [PSCustomObject] @{ DebugMode = $true }` and now you can access `$modes.a` directly (or indirectly by looping over `$modes.Keys`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Why not put that as an answer? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe **New-Variable** may help:

```
$thisName = "a"
$theseParams = @{ Name = $thisName; DebugMode = $true }
New-Variable -Name $thisName -Value $theseParams
```

The output seems to be what you're asking for:

```
PS C:\> $a.Name
a
PS C:\> $a

Name                           Value
----                           -----
DebugMode                      True
Name                           a
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is indeed literally what is asked for, but it's rarely what you actually want, because 1) the resulting variables are hard to use, requiring `Get-Variable` if you don't know their name until runtime, 2) it's easy to clash with an existing variable inadvertently, since there are a lot of those in scope at any time and 3) you can't easily find "your" variables again to loop over, if that's needed. It's most advisable to use `New-Variable` only with a static name, for those cases where you need the extra options (`-Scope`, `-Option ReadOnly`).